# How to run this app that uses cocoa pods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I downloaded this zip https://github.com/Loadex/MessageBanner but have no idea to install it correctly to run. All the app does is show custom iOS banners. I'd like for someone with cocoa pods experience to get this app to run locally and explain from the download process, what they did in a nice compact answer. I'd like a step by step explaining how to get it to run. Thanks. So far I've tried this but deleted the project folder after numerous warnings from the terminal and from Xcode at run time. I have cocoa pods installed.

```
WTL2:~ Apple$ cd desktop
WTL2:desktop Apple$ cd m
WTL2:m Apple$ cd MessageBannerDemo
WTL2:MessageBannerDemo Apple$ touch podfile
WTL2:MessageBannerDemo Apple$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.36.0.beta.2 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `MessageBannerDemo.xcworkspace`.

[!] [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
WTL2:MessageBannerDemo Apple$
```

Also added this to podfile

```
source 'git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MessageBanner', '~> 1.0'
```

Comment: Did you run `pod install` in the directory, in which the `Podfile` is located?

Comment: I just did and I will update my question with what just happened

Comment: In which directory you called into ? cd into `MessageBannerDemo`

Comment: yes i just tried that @dehlen

Comment: Have a look at this : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2723

Comment: yes, just took a look. dude had my same problem but i get the same error

Comment: Can you show your Podfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Podfile like that and run pod install :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MessageBanner'
```

Comment: just tried it and after trying to pod install got the same error above...?

Comment: Your error was about git@github.com:youboox/youboox-ios-specs.git and it's not in the Podfile anymore so it can't be the same error.

Comment: it says you can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` what could that be in this case?

Comment: Yes change `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` to `'git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git` like it says in the link I provided earlier.

Comment: I downloaded the repo, changed the Podfile like above, opened the .xcworkspace and it build & run just fine.

Comment: `git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MessageBanner', '~> 1.0' ` still doesn't work for me. Is this correct?

Comment: how did you open the .workspace? the compiler told me to use  MessageBannerDemo.xcworkspace. I want to know how to open that from the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

if you have not updated ruby gem and not installed cocoa pod, then follow “setup to use cocoa pods ” and after that “To run the project”. If you have already installed cocoapod,then you may leave option ‘A’. but it is recommended to follow ‘A’ then ‘B” both.

**A. setup to use cocoa pods**

> Open terminal and follow the following steps
>
> 1. update ruby gem
>
> `“sudo gem update —system”`
>
> Enter you system password when requested. wait it until it finished.
>   it may take little time
>   After  successful installation you will see something like this.

```
Ruby Interactive (ri) documentation was installed. ri is kind of like man 
pages for ruby libraries. You may access it like this:
  ri Classname
  ri Classname.class_method
  ri Classname#instance_method
If you do not wish to install this documentation in the future, use the
--no-document flag, or set it as the default in your ~/.gemrc file. See
'gem help env' for details.

RubyGems system software updated
```

> 2. Install cocoapods
>
> `“sudo gem install cocoapods”`
>
> you may get this to override press just enter Y to continue.
>   after successful installation you will see something similar to this

```
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-0.36.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.36.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.36.0
20 gems installed
```

> 3. to complete the setup of CocoaPods
>
> `“pod setup”`
>
> after successful, you will see something similar to this.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
    Setting up CocoaPods master repo
    Setup completed
```

**B. To Run downloaded Project**

> Open Terminal and follow the these steps
>
> 1. go to the location of your project.
>
> `ex cd ~/desktop/myProjects/TestCocoapod`
>
> 2. tell cocoapod to install the dependencies for your project.
>
> `“pod install”`
>
> After successful install, you will see something like this

```
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `TestCocoapod.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
```

> 3.Note: after this open the folder containing that project. You must 
>   always open the .xcworkspace (ex. TestCocoapod.xcworkspace).
>
> 4Now run the project. you can successfully run it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Podfile is correctly formatted:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

workspace 'MessageBannerDemo.xcworkspace'

# Make sure xcodeproj is in correct path. Or update path here.
xcodeproj 'MessageBannerDemo/MessageBannerDemo.xcodeproj'

pod 'MessageBanner'

# Specify Xcode project targets to link the default pod with.
link_with 'MessageBannerDemo'
```

Try "rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock" and then "pod install" again.

Comment: what is "rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock"? how do i run that?

Comment: did you get the program running? its from this link https://github.com/Loadex/MessageBanner if you get it to run Id love to know what you did set by step.

Comment: "rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock" is to delete "Pods" folder and "Podfile.lock" from your "MessageBannerDemo" project directory. Alternatively you can move these to trash in Finder window.

Comment: Did your issue got resolved? "Wanna take a look?" What? where?

Comment: shouldn't i be using `edit podfile ` command ? after I input that (after inputing `touch podfile` i get an error with edit podfile and now can't find it at all (command not found)

Comment: Do you think you can run the app?